# Is this possible to do H264 CCTV DVR + FreeNAS + FTP?

Tags: home-networking, nas, h.264, dvr

Can I use the storage inside H264 CCTV DVR as my NAS (network-attached storage) and use Filezilla to access the files remotely?

Comment: This is going to depend on the hardware you have.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You will not be able to load the FreeNAS software onto the DVR without significant modification to the unit. This would also render it useless as a DVR.